# How does AWS IOT's device gateway provide bi-directional communication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

One of the [core features](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/features/) of AWS IOT is to provide bi-directional communication through the device gateway. Knowing that the implementation is private, can anyone conceptually explain how the gateway is able to push messages to a device on my local network? Does the service maintain a persistent connection to the device?

To add context, in my experience prior to AWS IOT, if I wanted to communicate with my embedded app (using HTTP) I would need to set up port-forwarding, so it's a mystery to me why device gateway could work without this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS IOT is implemented with MQTT, an MQTT connection is permanent TCP connection from the device to the gateway (broker), meaning that when there is a need to send a message to the device this connection is used.

Because the connection is initiated from the device to the gateway there is no need to set up any port forwarding (apart from that which is automatically handled by a home router doing NAT)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Aside from the spec, is there a resource on mqtt that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT, uses the Pub/Sub pattern to provide communication between devices and message broker.

> Publish–subscribe is a messaging pattern where senders of messages,
>   called publishers, do not program the messages to be sent directly to
>   specific receivers, called subscribers, but instead categorize
>   published messages into classes without knowledge of which
>   subscribers, if any, there may be. Similarly, subscribers express
>   interest in one or more classes and only receive messages that are of
>   interest, without knowledge of which publishers, if any, there are.

More about this pattern here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649664.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with pub sub, but my question is really about what gives the service the ability to address my device, even if it's behind a local router.